# jQuery object where properties are DOM elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom

I'm looking for a more succint and possibly more jQuery-e way of doing the following.
I have an object `lbl` which is a div.  Contained within the div is a span tag that is the `firstName` and `lastName` property of the `lbl` object.  So, so far we have the following HTML:

```
<div class="label">
        <span class="firstName">John</span>
         <span class="lastName">Doe</span>
</div>
```

Now consider the following fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/VfErV/

```
 $('#btnSubmit').click(function ()
            {
                var lbl = $('<div>').addClass('label');
                //I need to be able to access the child elements of the parent div
                //via the dot operator
                firstName = $('<span>').text('test1').addClass('firstName');
                lastName = $('<span>').text('test2').addClass('lastName');
                lbl.append(firstName);
                lbl.append(lastName);
                lbl.firstName = firstName;
                lbl.lastName = lastName;

                $('#page').append(lbl);
                console.log(lbl.firstName.text());

                //span tag is never added to the div
                var lbl2 = $('<div>').addClass('label');
                lbl2.firstName = $('<span>').text('test2').addClass('firstName');
                $('#page').append(lbl2);
            });
```

Please refer to the fiddle for behavior.  I need to be able to control font-sizes, borders, etc. on the child objects of the parent div container, `lbl`, and have the appear on the page as normal DOM elements.  All of the JS up until the first lbl control is appended to the page works.  This looks clunky to me, though.  Is there a better way to have child elements of a DOM element be properties of the parent object more easily/succintly?

Comment: You don't need to do `lbl.firstName = firstName`, you can just do `lbl.children('.firstName')` to get the `<span>`.

Comment: Why have a DOM object as a property of a DOM object?  It's much more common to make it a child object (in the DOM) and then just keep it hidden if you don't want it to be visible most of the time.  Or, if you aren't going to make it visible, then why have a DOM object at all.  Just use `.data()` on `lbl` or `lbl2` to store the desired text.

Comment: @jfriend00 In this scenario I wish to take a parse a list of names to get first and last and create a div for each which looks like the label class.  It was my thinking that it would be best to do something like `lbl.firstName` and this give me access to the span tag with the `firstName` class..but this has goe me thinking maybe that wasn't the best of ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You asked for a more jQuery-way to do this.  Here's how you could create your structure:

```
$('#btnSubmit').click(function () {
    var lbl = $('<div>').addClass('label');
    lbl.html('<span class="firstName">test1</span><span class="lastName">test2</span>');
    $('#page').append(lbl);

    // Then, to retrieve that data, you can just do something like this
    console.log(lbl.find(".firstName").text());
});
```

Then, anytime you want to get the firstName from a given label div, you just use `.find("firstName")` to get that object and then get its text.

Best practices generally just use the structure of the DOM and find things as needed in the DOM rather than make new duplicate ways to access everything.  For 99% of what we do, accessing things through the DOM is plenty fast and doesn't require creation and duplication of another way to get to the data.  And, jQuery makes it pretty easy to find things in the DOM as long as you have enough id or class markers to identify what you're looking for (which you do).

Comment: OK, this makes sense.  So instead of making a DOM element a property of a DOM element I set `lbl.firstName` equal to the child span element that hasClass firstName.  Is that right?

Comment: I was under the impression that I could do some magic and if I did `lbl.firstName = $('<span>').text(John Doe')` it would magically work..needless to say it didn't.

Comment: @wootscootinboogie - it is NOT my recommendation to use a custom property on `lbl` at all.  That is NOT a best practice.  I recommended that when you have a `lbl` object, you just find the firstName in it when you need it and NOT store a separate way to access it.  Putting DOM references in properties is also sometimes a problem for memory leaks.  If you want to store a property on a DOM object, jQuery recommends that you use `.data()` as in `lbl.data("firstName", "whatever");`, but I don't see any reason to use that here.  When you need the firstName, just find it in the DOM and retrieve it.

Comment: OK, makes perfect sense now.  +1